# maven-release-plugin replacing scm.url /hg/hg/ with /hg//

Tags: maven, mercurial, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release some code hosted in a Mercurial repository at http://hg/hg/foo/bar

When I run `mvn -e --batch-mode release:prepare -X` I see that the maven-release-plugin log

```
[DEBUG] pushing to http://hg//foo/bar
[DEBUG] abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
[ERROR]
EXECUTION FAILED
  Execution of cmd : push failed with exit code: 255.
  Working directory was:
    /home/jfreedman/hg/foo/bar
```

If I then edit release.properties and change the scm.url property to `http://hg/%68g/foo/bar` I am able to release fine.

I am at a loss as to what's going on or how to fix it.